# ROR ways of calling destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I ask this question only because I'm curious.

The first line is standard, RESTful and of course invokes destroy method.
The second line returns a routing error.

The question is how to repair the second line to work like the first one. As I mentioned before, It's just for my curiosity and better ROR understanding.

```
<%= link_to 'delete', file, :method => :delete %></td>
<%= link_to 'delete', {:action => :destroy, :controller => 'files', :id => file.id.to_s}, :method => :delete %>
```

Bye

Comment: This should work <%= link_to 'delete', :action => :destroy, :controller => 'files' %>

Comment: Your `:method` is wrong on the 2nd one, should be `:delete`, or is that a type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I know this is not the way to do a delete. It is proof of concept on just how to access an action via a controller outside of REST.

You can do this:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', {:action => :destroy, :controller => 'files', :id => file.id} %>
```

You don't need the method destroy if you explicitly access the action. Also don't need the to_s for the file.id

Comment: IIRC, yes, you must use the :delete method, that's the whole point of REST.

Comment: REST request to the resource's route should include the method

Comment: I realize that you need :delete for the rest method. I was answering why his second line was throwing an error. The top line is the correct way of doing it. If you read the question "The question is how to repair the second line to work like the first one. As I mentioned before, It's just for my curiosity and better ROR understanding."